# instruments: memory leak when creating UIButton

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, uibutton, instruments, iboutlet

I am trying to find out why when creating an UIButton in interface builder - a memory leak occurs when running the instruments application by xcode.

This is how I created the memory leak.

I opened a new application, opened up the myAppViewController.xib file in interface builder.
I changed the background to black. 
Added a UIButton, renamed it to "foo" title.
saved and then exit.

In the myAppViewController.h file i have the following

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface miPlanNewViewController : UIViewController { 
    IBOutlet UIButton *tasksProjects; 
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton *tasksProjects;
@end
```

in the myAppViewController.m file i have the following:

```
#import "miPlanNewViewController.h"

@implementation miPlanNewViewController
@synthesize tasksProjects;

...
//the normal methods you get
...
- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Here is a screen shot of what I am getting at the moment in instruments.

[image]
[image]

One thing i notice however....

I haven't connected the Outlet to the uibutton yet in interface builder, BUT when I delete the UIButton from interface builder, save, and then run the program with instruments again, I dont get any sort of leaks at all.

Can someone please explain what is happening and how I can solve this issue. Thank you.

Comment: Do you see this when testing on device, rather than the simulator? As per Apple's recommendations, you should never use the iOS Simulator for memory leak checking, because the simulator will leak in places where the device won't.

Comment: ... I see. However, in my other projects, the simulator leaks at the same place, and also closes the application sometimes when ive switched between views say about ten times. is this also because im on the simulator? surely the simulator shouldnt close my app just because its the simulator. sometimes i can see te exc_bad_access warning when the simulator closes down which in most cases signify a leak?

Comment: If your app is getting closed because of memory issues, it isn't going to be because of the leak you're seeing above. It's only leaking 128 bytes, that's nothing. You could leak that thousands of times over and still not get a memory warning. What I'm saying is you *shouldn't use the simulator for memory debugging*. The simulator does not reflect what goes on in device. You *must* use the device for memory leak testing and debugging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Firstly, you're not releasing the property.
  in dealloc you should have 
  `[tasksProjects release];` and in viewDidUnload you should have `self.taskProjects = nil;`
- Secondly, as lxt metioned you shouldn't be using the simulator for memory leak checking.
- Thirdly, check that you're building release not debug.

Comment: What is wrong with using debug build and simulator?